# Total count for a limited result

Tags: dojo, symfony, doctrine-orm

So i implemented the paging for [dojo.store.jsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) to use as store in the dojox.grid.DataGrid. In the server im using *Symfony 2* and as ORM *Doctrine*, im new to this two frameworks.

For Dojo jsonRest the response of the server must have a header **Content-Range** containing the result **offset**, **limit** and the **total number of records (without the limit)**.

So for a response with a **Content-Range: items 0-24/66** header, if the user where to scroll the grid records to the **24 row**, it will make a async request with **Range: 24-66** header, then the response header should have a **Content-Range: items 24-66/66**. This is done so Dojo can know how many request it can make for the paginated data and the records range for the presented and subsequent request.

So my problem is that to get the total number of records without the limit, i had to make a **COUNT** query using the same query that has the offset and limit. I don't like this.

**I want to know if there is a way i can get the total count and the limited result without making two queries.**

```
public function getByTextCount($text)
{
    $dql = "SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM Bundle:Something s WHERE s.text LIKE :text";

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
    $query->setParameter('text', '%'.$text.'%');

    return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

-

```
public function getByText($text, $offset=0, $limit=24)
{
    $dql = "SELECT r FROM Bundle:Something s WHERE s.text LIKE :text";

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
    $query->setParameter('text', '%'.$text.'%');
    $query->setFirstResult($offset);
    $query->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

Comment: Doubtful though maybe someone will know.  The database will almost certainly cache the total query so the overhead will be minimal.

Comment: I thought so too, but will see. Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you can do a `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the number
>   of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is
>   desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned
>   without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain
>   this row count, include a SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT
>   statement, and then invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Doctrine only (i.e. to avoid vendor-specific SQL) you can always reset part of the query after you have selected the entities:

```
    // $qb is a Doctrine Query Builder
    // $query is the actual DQL query returned from $qb->getQuery()
    // and then updated with the ->setFirstResult(OFFSET) and ->setMaxResults(LIMIT)

    // Get the entities as an array ready for JSON serialization
    $entities = $query->getArrayResult();

    // Reset the query and get the total records ready for the Range header
    // 'e' in count(e) is the alias for the entity specified in the Query Builder
    $count = $qb->resetDQLPart('orderBy')
                ->select('COUNT(e)')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleScalarResult();
```